# pandas dataframe group year index by decade

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a dataframe with index as monthy timestep, I know I can use `dataframe.groupby(lambda x:x.year)` to group monthly data into yearly and apply other operations. Is there some way I could quick group them, let's say by decade?

thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 41):

To get the decade, you can integer-divide the year by 10 and then multiply by 10.  For example, if you're starting from

```
>>> dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2001', periods=500, freq="M")
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": 5*np.arange(len(dates))+2}, index=dates)
>>> df.head()
             A
2001-01-31   2
2001-02-28   7
2001-03-31  12
2001-04-30  17
2001-05-31  22
```

You can group by year, as usual (here we have a `DatetimeIndex` so it's really easy):

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index.year).sum().head()
         A
2001   354
2002  1074
2003  1794
2004  2514
2005  3234
```

or you could do the `(x//10)*10` trick:

```
>>> df.groupby((df.index.year//10)*10).sum()
           A
2000   29106
2010  100740
2020  172740
2030  244740
2040   77424
```

If you don't have something on which you can use `.year`, you could still do `lambda x: (x.year//10)*10)`.

Answer (score 6):

if your Data Frame has Headers say : `DataFrame ['Population','Salary','vehicle count']`

Make your index as Year: `DataFrame=DataFrame.set_index('Year')`

use below code to resample data in decade of 10 years and also gives you some of all other columns within that dacade

`datafame=dataframe.resample('10AS').sum()`

Comment: Best solution, without any workaround. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: This is perfect. I run it on my datetime variable (and a variable called "t_0_low") and that works, too. See: 
g_1 = dfm.set_index('datetime').resample('10AS')['t_0_low'].sum()

Answer (score 2):

Use the year attribute of index:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year)
```

Comment: this will group by year, not by decade, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

lets say your date column goes by the name `Date`, then you can group up

**`dataframe.set_index('Date').ix[:,0].resample('10AS', how='count')`**

Note: the `ix` - here chooses the first column in your dataframe

You get the various offsets: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases