# Group by Issue with Years Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm following the answer for this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764619/pandas-dataframe-group-year-index-by-decade) to group a column of years by decades to make it easier for me to visualize later, but I'm not getting the same results. It seems like when DSM did it, it yielded integers for years, while mine is yielding floats for years.

I've implemented:

```
p_b['yr_built'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yr_built'], format='%Y', errors='coerce').dt.to_period('Y')
p_b= p_b.set_index('yr_built')
p_b1= p_b.groupby((p_b.index.year/10)*10).mean()
```

My Results: [Picture of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6ttK.png)

Comment: I think you mean to use `//` instead of `/` to group every 10 years.

Comment: @ALollz that was the issue, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another /, I.e. p_b.index.year//.